# Do we have a policy or guidance for questions with no one right answer?

Tags: discussion, best-practices, accepted-answer

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/522163/) does not seem to have a single correct answer posted.
Which of the following are true:

1. Assume that there will never be one right answer posted (i.e. because there is not in principle a right answer).

   1. This was a bad question and should be closed/deleted.
   2. Leave it how it is. It's ok that there will never be an accepted answer for this question.
   3. We should post a new answer with a list of all relevant good information taken from other good answers in the thread, and mark that new one as accepted. That answer can be updated to include any relevant information from new answers that show up.
2. Assume that a right answer may eventually be posted, so leave it how it is until the messiah answer arrives.
3. Other.

I kind of don't like options 1.2 or 2 because it's been long enough that I *feel* like I should accept something.
Then again, I really believe in the integrity of the accept button and I want to use it where it's deserved.

Comment: Both answers are upvoted and no one expressed dissent or disagreement with their content. Why haven't you left a comment? Are you 100% both answers are wrong?

Comment: If there is no (one) right answer then the question is not a good fit for SE overall.

Comment: @JonCuster Resource requests are an obvious exception. With that in mind, perhaps we could refine your comment?

Comment: Orthogonal to the question but I'm curious as to what exactly is wrong about the existing answers? They both look fine to me, I wouldn't hesitate accepting either of them.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform How would you choose which one to accept?

Comment: @DanielSank Perhaps "complex amplitude" is the least ambiguous and most descriptive name? Zachos also seems to confirm that these words are also used in related contexts. But anyway, this doesn't really affect the core of your post so I don't want to distract from the topic.